# How to implement asymmetric relationship in machine learning Classification algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to build a classification system, that takes pairs of images as input and output {0 or 1} if image B is sub-category of image A.

Below are some examples of the data.

- Input: Image A [Apple Tree] & Image B [Apple] | Output: [1]
- Input: [Orange Tree] & [Orange] | Output: [1]
- Input: [Apple Tree] & [Orange Tree] | Output: [0]
- Input: [Apple] & [Apple Tree] | Output: [0]

This requires asymmetric relationship (apple tree --> apple but not the other way around) in the model architecture and I struggled to find structures to help with this situation.

I have tried researching on product recommendation / clothing compatibility papers because they seem to have asymmetric relationship (e.g. Laptop to charger). But most of the research seem to use collaborative filtering without addressing the asymmetry  issue.

Is there any model structures or papers that address the asymmetry problem? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using some kind of data augmentation to teach your model the nature of the problem, let's say your model has an input layer to accept 2 images and a flag to show desire relation, what if you adding some synthetic pairs to clarify the problem (direction of the relation) to the model. precisely you can add another synthetic sample for each positive (label=1) record with the label 0 just by reversing the order of the images!

```
[Orange Tree] & [Orange] | Label: [1] # Real
[Orange] & [Orange Tree] | Label: [0] # Synthetic
```